# How do you allow emdash in the text of your document?

Tags: xetex, unicode

Currently, if an emdash makes it into the text, it is omitted in the output PDF, which is very frustrating, especially given that its easy to miss. Here is the basic set of headings I use in documents. I am throwing more headings in there than are needed, as I am not sure if the headings would interfere with any proposed solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{ellipsis}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[pass, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{works-cited.bib}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}

\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox}

\begin{document}
This is text—has an emdash.
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image: emdash example]

I am aware that there are some solutions that involve defining a latex command that allows you to render a dash, but typing the dash directly is so second nature to me that I don't realise that I am even doing it. I would like to be able to type more than ASCI characters, it is 2017 after all. :D

Comment: Uh, what's the purpose of `\usepackage{newtxtext}` in XeLaTeX?

Comment: And don't use the fontenc package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is in loading `newtxtext` that's for `pdflatex` and not XeLaTeX.

Also, be more consistent with your package loading: first the packages, then the setup, in general.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass, a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ellipsis}
\usepackage{relsize,etoolbox}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\setmainlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{greek}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{GFS Artemisia}

\addbibresource{works-cited.bib}

\begin{document}
This is text—has an emdash.

Some math: $a+b=\sin\alpha$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, I am still learning TeX, sometimes I forget why I have copied and pasted things, this one was probably a hangover from when I was using PDFLatex.

Comment: +1, another thing I'd like to mention is that everyone should set `\tracinglostchars=1` in their preamble or whatever; from a user-experience perspective it's a usability bug to silently ignore characters which don't exist, rather than warn loudly about them.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR IIRC, setting the parameter to 2 makes XeTeX stop for an error.

Answer (score 4):

Remove `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` which has nothing to do with `fontspec` and add. As noted by @egreg, I'm not sure `newtxtext` is useful here.

```
\setmainfont{TeXGyreTermesX}
```

[image]

Comment: Here you are, since apparently you can't live without braces… ;o)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've removed `fontenc`, I think that was a hangover from when I was using pdflatex. Incidentally, it was removing `newtxtext` that enabled emdash. Removing `fontenc` has had a different effect that I now need to resolve (:

Comment: Could post a code that demonstrates this effect?